# Get specific values from response

Tags: javascript

I get this ajax response:

```
{"0":{"id":1,"value":"73.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22","updated_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22"},"7":{"id":8,"value":"73.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-03 20:13:22","updated_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22"},"8":{"id":9,"value":"73.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-06 19:48:31","updated_at":"2020-05-06 19:48:31"}}
```

And i would like to extract only the values from each row. This obviously didnt work:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = {"0":{"id":1,"value":"73.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22","updated_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22"},"7":{"id":8,"value":"73.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-03 20:13:22","updated_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22"},"8":{"id":9,"value":"73.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-06 19:48:31","updated_at":"2020-05-06 19:48:31"}}

const value = Object.values(data).map(e => e.value)

console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

should have a better solution, but it works

```
const values = Object.values(json).map(({ value})  => value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the response has already been parsed.If you want to loop as in your example through each item,

```js
const result = Object.values(data);
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
           console.log(result[i].value);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use **for in loop** to map objects:

```js
const data = {"0":{"id":1,"value":"72.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22","updated_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22"},"7":{"id":8,"value":"73.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-03 20:13:22","updated_at":"2020-05-04 20:13:22"},"8":{"id":9,"value":"74.0","tracker_id":1,"created_at":"2020-05-06 19:48:31","updated_at":"2020-05-06 19:48:31"}};

for (key in data) {
  console.log(data[key].value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with This:

```
Object.values(a).map(p => console.log(p.value));
```